# Querying database from different applications with nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, architecture

In this moment, I have two web applications(one application is an MVC2 application for the management of my project and the second is an application with web services). Both applications have to deal with the database and have Nhibernate for querying the database. Is this a good pattern?, if not what can i do?

**Edit 1**

Both applications can write to the database. I have a dll project that handle the database transactions and have de nhibernate instance named "Repositorio". Nevertheless, each application will have a different instance of Repositorio.dll so there is going to be multiple threats to the database, what do i have to do to make both application use the same instance of Repositorio.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on whether or not both applications can write to the database.

If one is read-only, I'd say you're safe.

I not, I'd argue that a service-oriented approach would recommend creating a service that provided an interface for both applications and was the sole owner of the database.

"service-oriented" does not mean that the service has to be a distributed component (e.g., SOAP or REST or RPC).  If you encapsulate the database access in a component with a well-defined interface you can choose to share the component as a DLL in both applications.  Only make it a distributed component if that makes sense for both applications.

Comment: Both applications can write to the database. I have a dll project that handle the database transactions and have de nhibernate instance named "Repositorio". Nevertheless, each application will have a different instance of Repositorio.dll so there is going to be multiple threats to the database, what do i have to do to make both application use the same instance of Repositorio.dll?

Comment: You have to worry about transactions and isolation.  They both can have the same DLL, so that's shared.  You just have to make sure that their write operations are serializable.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds perfectly fine to me even if both applications write to the database. I would simply recommend you create a third project as a class library with all your nHibernate related stuff to avoid writing any redundant code in both projects.